What is an "equivariant" homotopy with respect to deck transformations?
In A Primer on Mapping Class Groups (p. 27) the following passage on "simple closed curves in the torus" appears:

Let $\mathbb{R}^2 \to T^2$ be the usual covering map, where the deck transformation group is generated by the translations by $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$. [. . .]
Let $\gamma$ be any oriented simple closed curve in $T^2$.
Up to homotopy, we can assume that $\gamma$ passes through the image in $T^2$ of $(0, 0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Any path lifting of $\gamma$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ based at the origin terminates at some integral point $(p, q)$.
There is then a homotopy from $\gamma$ to the standard straight-line representative of $(p, q) \in \pi_1(T^2)$; indeed, the straight-line homotopy from the lift of $\gamma$ to the straight line through $(0, 0)$ and $(p, q)$ is equivariant with respect to the group of deck transformations and thus descends to the desired homotopy.
Now, if a closed curve in $T^2$ is simple, then its straight-line representative  is simple.

Let $\pi \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to T^2$ denote the covering map, $\mathrm{Deck}(\pi)$ the group of deck transformations and $H \colon [0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ the homotopy.
According to Wikipedia, for $H$ to be equivariant with respect to $\mathrm{Deck}(\pi)$, the domain $[0,1]^2$ would need to be a $\mathrm{Deck}(\pi)$-set.

What group action on $[0,1]^2$ is implied here, and why is this choice made?
Why is equivariance of $H$ important in ensuring the homotopy descends to $T^2$?

Any clarification on this would be greatly appreciated!

They are using different equivariance condition, whe the group acts on the space of paths $\gamma$ and on the space of homotopies $H$.

@MoisheKohan Do you mean paths in the covering space like the lift of $\gamma$? What equivariance condition are they using exactly?

See the answer.

The whole passage is garbled. Here is what they should have said (and probably meant to say):

Let $G\cong \mathbb Z^2\cong \pi_1(T^2, \mathbf 0)$ denote the group of covering transformations of $\pi$. Here $\mathbf 0=\pi((0,0))$. Let $\gamma: [0,1]\to T^2, \gamma(0)=\gamma(1)$, be any oriented simple loop in $T^2$. After a free  homotopy of $\gamma$ (which homotopy we take is ultimately irrelevant since $G$ is abelian), we can assume that $\gamma(0)=\mathbf 0$. Given a point $r=(p,q)\in \mathbb Z^2\subset \mathbb R^2$, let $\tilde \gamma_r$ denote the unique lift of $\gamma$ to a path which starts at a point $r$ and (necessarily) terminates at a point $r'=g_\gamma(r)\in \mathbb Z^2$, where $g_\gamma\in G$ is the element represented by $[\gamma]\in \pi_1(T^2, \mathbf 0)\cong G$.


There is then a homotopy from $\gamma$ to the standard straight-line representative of $[\gamma] \in \pi_1(T^2)$. Indeed, the straight-line homotopy $H_r$ (relative the end-points) from $\tilde\gamma_r$ to the straight line segment from $r$ to  $r'$ is equivariant with respect to the $G$-action on $\mathbb R^2$, in the sense that for every $g\in G$,
$$
g\circ H_r= H_{g(r)}. 
$$
Thus, $H_r$ descends to the desired homotopy.

